# Printing randomly from a list OCAML

Tags: ocaml

How do I print each line in a text file only once but in a random order?

I have a text file that containts six individual lines and I am trying to print them to the screen randomly

Here is the code I have so far

```
open Scanf 
open Printf

let id x = x 
let const x = fun _ -> x
let read_line file = fscanf file "%s@\n" id 
let is_eof file = try fscanf file "%0c" (const false) with End_of_file -> true


let _ = 
  let file = open_in "text.txt" in 
  while not (is_eof file) do 
    let s = read_line file in
    printf "%s\n" s 
  done;

  close_in file
```

I could append elements "s" into a list. Printing elements in a list can be as simple as following however, I am not sure how to print elements in the list randomly.

```
let rec print_list = function 
[] -> ()
| e::l -> print_int e ; print_string " " ; print_list l
```

Answer (score 0):

let's define a function that retrieve one element identified by its position in a list, and return a tuple (this_element, the_list_wo_this_element).

```
Ex : pick [0;2;4;6;8] 3
returns (6, [0;2;4;8)).
```

Then, by iterating on the resulted list (the rhs of the tuple above), you pick a random element from that list , until that list is empty.

Comment: Random access on lists is inefficient. Depending on the size of the data it may be more efficient to convert your list to an array and operate on that. If needed, the array can be converted back to a list.